# Pushing elements through left won't work properly

Tags: html, css

I'm just new learning HTML form elements. How can I properly push my input and select elements to the left? I align my elements to left `float: right` and align my text to the right `align-text: left` but it didn't pushing to the left.

**Code:**

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="addBooks">
    <h1>Add Books</h1>
    <hr>
    <form action="#">
      <fieldset>
        <label for="bookname">Book Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="bookname" name="bookname">
        <br />
        <label for="category">Category:</label>
        <select name="category">
          <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <label for="author">Author:</label>
        <select name="author">
          <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
        </select>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div><!--- end of addBooks --->
</div><!--- end of container --->
```

so I wrap my `div class = "addBooks"` with `div id = "container`.

**Css:**

```
.addBooks {
  clear: both;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10%;
}
.addBooks label {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: right;
}
.addBooks input {
  float: right;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: left;
}
.addBooks select {
  float: right;
  text-align: left;
}
```

I'm planning to push my elements to the mid-left like this. Thanks for the help!

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `float: right;` to do this but you can use `margin-left` instead :

```
.addBooks input
{
    width: 150px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 200px
}

.addBooks select
{
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 200px
}
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mn0k58dg/6/)

Comment: This is what I've been looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your Problem ..your `div` is 800px and you use 150px for lable .. Now you have 650px left on your div.. you set your `input` to 150px and say `float:right` this will pull the input to right in the remaining 650px.

**Solution is to NOT add float rule to your input  and select tag** and by default you will get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

possible answer [not tested]

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="addBooks">
    <h1>Add Books</h1>
    <hr>
    <form action="#">
      <fieldset>
        <label for="bookname">Book Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="bookname" name="bookname">
        <br />
        <label for="category">Category:</label>
        <select name="category">
          <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <label for="author">Author:</label>
        <select name="author">
          <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
        </select>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div><!--- end of addBooks --->
</div><!--- end of container --->
```

so I wrap my `div class = "addBooks"` with `div id = "container`.

**Css:**

```
.addBooks {
  clear: both;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  text-align:centre;
}
.addBooks label {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: right;
}
.addBooks input {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: left;
}
.addBooks select {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  width:150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While @Vincent provided a solution, I'd like to introduce you to a better way to manage your DOM structure: `flexbox`.

I've had an example up for years at: http://codepen.io/bddenhartog/pen/bdRwqp